# Simple "identify and replace" Excel VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns 'A' and 'B'. In column 'A', I have only characters. Column 'B' is blank for the time being, as follows.

***QUESTION 01:*** What code should I use to indicate that whenever "aaa" or "ddd" appears, the corresponding cell of column 'B', next to column 'A', would automatically change to "YES"?

***QUESTION 02:*** At this point, the word "YES" written in VBA code in cells B1 and B4 cannot be deleted or altered (cells are locked). On the other hand, cells B2 and B3 (those written "NO") can be manipulated by the user. Note that I have also to protect the blocked "YES" cells with a password.

***QUESTION 03:*** How can I do it programmatically using my password = "mypass"?, so as the user would not need to type a password to unblock the cell when VBA writes the "NO" in the process.

**Before**

Col. A  .....    Col.B (empty column)

A1.aaa  ..... B1.
A2.bbb  ..... B2.
A3.ccc  ...... B3.
A4.ddd  ..... B4.

**After**

Col. A  .....    Col.B

A1.aaa  ..... B1.YES
A2.bbb  ..... B2.NO
A3.ccc  ...... B3.NO
A4.ddd  ..... B4.YES

```
Sheets("Plan1").Activate
If Range("A1:A4").Select = "aaa" Then
    Range("B1:B4").Value = "YES"
If Range("A1:A4").Select = "ddd" Then
    Range("B1:B4").Value = "YES"
    Range("B1:B4").Select
    Selection.Locked = True
    Selection.FormulaHidden = False
    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, 
    Scenarios:=True
    ActiveSheet.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
Else:
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    Range("B1:B4").Value = "NO"
```

Comment: `ANSWER 01` See [THIS](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) `ANSWER 02` Loop through the cells and individually set the ".Locked" property to "True" or "False". Finally protect the sheet. `ANSWER 03` Either use "ActiveSheet.Protect MYPASSWORD" or read about ".UserInterfaceOnly"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q1:**

You could apply simple `IF` formula to the entire range and then rewrite cells values with result of this formula:

```
With .Range("B1:B4")
    .Formula = "=IF(OR(A1=""aaa"", A1=""ddd""),""YES"",""NO"")"
    .Calculate
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

**Q2:**

You could loop through your range  and lock all cells, which value is "YES" (you could also use [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) method to detect cells with value "YES"):

```
For Each cell In .Range("B1:B4")
    cell.Locked = (cell = "YES")
Next cell
```

**Q3:**

Unprotect/protect sheet with password as simple as this:

```
With Sheets("Plan1")
    .Unprotect Password:=pass
    'YOUR CODE HERE
    .Protect Password:=pass
End With
```

**ADDITIONAL POINTS:**

If you already have some cells in the *UsedRange* locked on the previous run of code (or manually), you should store thouse addresses. I suggets you to use [Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251465%28v=office.15%29.aspx):

```
Dim lockArr As New Collection
```

and then store address of all locked cells in the *UsedRange*:

```
For Each cell In Sheets("Plan1").UsedRange
    If cell.Locked Then lockArr.Add cell.Address
Next
```

Next step is to unlock all cells on the sheet (initially Excel locks all cells on the sheet, even if they are empty and unused):

```
Sheets("Plan1").Cells.Locked = False
```

Finally, we lock only cells, that was previously locked in the *UsedRange*:

```
For Each addr In lockArr
    Sheets("Plan1").Range(addr).Locked = True
Next
```

**RESULT CODE:**

```
Sub test()
    Dim pass As String
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim lockArr As New Collection
    Dim addr

    pass = "mypass"

    With Sheets("Plan1")

        .Unprotect Password:=pass

        'find all locked cells
        For Each cell In .UsedRange
            If cell.Locked Then lockArr.Add cell.Address
        Next

        'unlock all cells on the sheet
        .Cells.Locked = False

        'lock previously locked cells
        For Each addr In lockArr
            .Range(addr).Locked = True
        Next

        With .Range("B1:B4")
            .Formula = "=IF(OR(A1=""aaa"", A1=""ddd""),""YES"",""NO"")"
            .Calculate
            .Value = .Value
            For Each cell In .Cells
                cell.Locked = (cell = "YES")
            Next cell
        End With

        .Protect Password:=pass, DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
        .EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
    End With

    Set lockArr = Nothing
End Sub
```

---

---

**UPD:**

change

```
With .Range("B1:B4")
    .Formula = "=IF(OR(A1=""aaa"", A1=""ddd""),""YES"",""NO"")"
    .Calculate
    .Value = .Value
    For Each cell In .Cells
        cell.Locked = (cell = "YES")
    Next cell
End With
```

to

```
With .Range("B1:B4")
   For Each cell In .Cells
      ' cell.Offset(, -1) means offset 1 to the left, i.e. column A
      'if value in column A mathes criteria then change value in col B to "YES", else do nothing
      If cell.Offset(, -1) = "aaa" Or cell.Offset(, -1) = "ddd" Then
         cell = "YES"
      End If
      cell.Locked = (cell = "YES")
   Next cell
End With
```

**Explanation of code above:**

- Since `cell` it's one of the cell from `.Range("B1:B4")`, `cell.Offset(, -1)` means offset 1 to the left, i.e. column A (e.g. if `cell` is `B2`, then `cell.Offset(, -1)` would refer to `A2`)
- Then we test criterias in line `If cell.Offset(, -1) = "aaa" Or cell.Offset(, -1) = "ddd" Then` - if corresponding cell in column `A` is "aaa" or "ddd", then change value in column `B` to "YES", otherwise do nothing with cell in column `B`
- Final step - `cell.Locked = (cell = "YES")` - if cell contains "YES", than lock it, else unlock.

Comment: Nice!Yet,there are many cells that I still need user interaction. Your solution blocks all cells, except those with "NO". However, please consider the following: Firstly, some few cells in columns (C,D,E.),for example, are already blocked to the user. I blocked them beforehand and used the password "1234". Those in any circumstance must remain blocked. Secondly, all the other cells should be available for user inputs, except those containing "YES" and,of course,those that I previously blocked myself with the password "1234".Could you possibly modify and implement that information to your code?

Comment: **I am facing another problem ;)**  According to your code, all the cells in column B that are equal to "aaa" or "ddd" receive "YES.  Suppose now that column B is not as empty as stated, but has letters in all cells. According to you, if cell B3 has "eee", it will turn to "NO". How to leave what is there without any changes?. I´ve tried this: .Formula="=IF(OR(a1=""aaa"", a1=""ddd""),""YES"",b1=b1)" but it does not work. For instance, if condition satisfies, do something, else do nothing (nothing = do not write zeros, do not erase, but leave it as is). Can you solve that?

Comment: So you need to write "Yes" or leave witout changes?

Comment: if so, see my UPD part of answer

Comment: Brilliant !! Very kind of you sharing all the detailed explanation and step by step tutorial. Cheers :)